# KeyError' in Python

Tags: pandas, machine-learning

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import numpy as np

dt = pd.read_csv("C:\Subhro\ML_Internship\MARUTI_2.csv")
data = pd.DataFrame(dt)

data = data.drop('Date',axis=1)
data.drop(['Unnamed: 0'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(data)

Roll_Mean_14 = data['Close Price'].rolling(window=14).mean()
Standard_Dev_14 = data['Close Price'].rolling(window=14).mean().std()
Upper_Band_14 = data['Close Price'].rolling(window=14).mean() + (2*Standard_Dev_14)                              
Low_Band_14 = data['Close Price'].rolling(window=14).mean() - (2*Standard_Dev_14)
avg_stock_price = data['Average Price']
stock_price = data['Close Price']

data['Roll_Avg'] = Roll_Mean_14
data['Upper_Band'] = Upper_Band_14
data['Lower_Band'] = Low_Band_14
data['Avg_Stock_Price'] = avg_stock_price

data=data.drop(data.head(14).index, inplace=False)
print(data)

for i in (data):
    if((data['Close Price'][i])<(data['Lower_Band'][i])):
        data['Call'][i]='Buy'
    elif((data['Close Price'][i])>(data['Lower Band'][i])) and ((data['Close Price'][i])<(data['Roll_Avg'])):
        data['Call'][i]='Hold Buy/Liquidate Short'
    elif((data['Close Price'][i])>(data['Roll_Avg'][i])) and ((data['Close Price'][i])<(data['Upper Band'])):
        data['Call'][i]='Hold Short/Liquidate Buy'   
    elif((data['Close Price'][i])>(data['Upper_Band'])):
        data['Call'][i]='Short'
print(data)
```

In this code, I have been creating a new column : 'Call' to print the categories 'Buy','Short','Hold Buy/Liquidate Short', 'Hold Short/Liquidate Buy' according to the conditions given in the code. On running the code it is showing me the error as

```
KeyError : 'Symbol' in line 
if((data['Close Price'][i])<(data['Lower_Band'][i])):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manner of accessing the indexes of the dataframe is incorrect.

You could try this :

```
for i in data.index:
    if((data[i]['Close Price'])<(data[i]['Lower_Band'])):
```

The way you access a particular value(cell) in a dataframe(table) is :

data[row_index][column_index]

Comment: Ok.. I did that... Now it's showing me Key Error : 'Call'

Comment: after doing the above mentioned change, I am now finding an error KeyError : 14 in the same line